# How can I pass array of hashes to a function in Powershell 2.0 and 3.0?

Tags: .net, powershell

How can I pass array of hashes to function that is in an imported module in Powershell?

And Is there a difference between Powershell 3.0 and 2.0? So that I can use a back compatible syntax?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no difference between PowerShell 2.0 and 3.0 in this area.  You simply create an array of hashtables and pass them into your function e.g.:

```
MyFunction @(@{name='ringo';age=72},@{name='paul';age=70})
```

Your function could be defined as either:

```
function MyFunction($hashtables) { ... }
```

or

```
function MyFunction([hashtable[]]$hashtables) { ... }
```